# How can I use AccessControl 2.5 in Mediawiki 1.23.3 properly?

Tags: php, permissions, mediawiki, access-control

I have installed `MediaWiki 1.23.3` in a `Windows XP SP3` box.

It works fine and I can edit content and I have also created a specific group called IT.

I have installed `AccessControl 2.5` in the `$WIKI_INSTAL_DIR/includes/AccessControl` path.

The documentation in [AccessControl official extension page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AccessControl) is proving to be a little hard to understand on how to properly implement.

For example I don't understand the correlation between a page, the users in a certain usergroup and the permissions that they should or should not have to access or not a page.

All I want to do, is to make some pages inaccessible to the **IT** usergroup.

How can I achieve this? ...

Comment: Ok .. here's me finding answers to my question yet again :) ... Apparently, AccessControl will protect/control/hide or whatever you call it, the content below the tag declaration like `<accesscontrol>...<accesscontrol>`. This works ok now but I only fear that the extension is not doing smth right because once I want to access the protected page from a user that does not belong to the granted usergroups, I get a blank page (I would have expected something sleeker to show instead just a blank page, NO?)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple, we are using it for our wiki. Just put on the page `<accesscontrol>group1,group2,group3</accesscontrol>` containing all the groups that **are** allowed to access the page.

You can edit the message displayed by editing the page Mediawiki:accesscontrol-info-box or Mediawiki:accesscontrol-info (can't remember which right now.)

Comment: I have added my custom user groups with `$wgGroupPermissions['CUSTOMUSERGROUP']['read'] = true`    but whenever I add <accesscontrol>CUSTOMUSERGROUP</accesscontrol> to a page ... the page goes all blank ... Could be PHP not parsing the end tag </accesscontrol> ???